# How to get only friends with profile photos uploaded, and ignore those users with the default silhouette?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, social-networking

I cannot figure a way get friends only with profile photos. I could use multi-query to check whether every friend has a photo, but that would incur heavy traffic.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Could you define what would be a friend without a photo? Do you mean the photo for Test Users display?

Comment: This is a friend without a photo https://graph.facebook.com/37005951/picture?type=large

Comment: May be all non-photos have only this image `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yL/r/HsTZSDw4avx.gif` . You can check if url of picture is this.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I would still need to make `2x` requests.

Comment: Just tried using this approach, though it is not an option. It takes 10 seconds to check data with 500 friends.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem to solve, did you managed to find a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lyuben Just added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Gajus’ suggested query *might* work right now, it’ll break once Facebook changes the URL of the default picture on their CDN. (Might happen, might not happen.)

So I’d suggest this for improvement:

The `profile_pic` table has a field called `is_silhouette`, which is a boolean for whether the user has their own profile picture set or not.

So to get only those of your friends, that have a profile picture set, you can use

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN
  (SELECT id FROM profile_pic WHERE
    id IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me() )
    AND NOT is_silhouette
  )
```

–> [Try this query in the Graph API Explorer.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=%20%20%20%20SELECT%20uid,%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%28SELECT%20id%20FROM%20profile_pic%20WHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid1%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid2%20%3D%20me%28%29%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AND%20NOT%20is_silhouette%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a simple FQL.

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND pic_small != 'https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yP/r/FdhqUFlRalU.jpg'
```

The seb-query will get all yours friend `uids`. The other query will match does uids with the profile data check if the `pic_small` is referring to what Facebook uses as a [placeholder](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yP/r/FdhqUFlRalU.jpg).

You can quickly test it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20uid,%20name,%20pic_small%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me%28%29%29%20AND%20pic_small%20!=%20%27https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yP/r/FdhqUFlRalU.jpg%27).