# Blank User Profile Picture

Tags: facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get only friends with profile photos uploaded, and ignore those users with the default silhouette?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827962/how-to-get-only-friends-with-profile-photos-uploaded-and-ignore-those-users-wit)

Is there a way to check if the user has a profile picture or just a plain blank picture using fql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs

> pic: The URL to the small-sized profile picture for the object being queried. The image can have a maximum width of 50px and a maximum height of 150px. **This URL may be blank.**

Although, doing this query:

```
select pic from user where uid = xxxx
```

On a user I *know* doesn't have a profile pic, returned this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "pic": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yV/r/Xc3RyXFFu-2.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```